# Transform body fat in muscle

Tags: workout, body-fat

I have read Internet,as I read body fat doesn't play a role about help buidling muscle.As i read need diet with foods,protein etc.On the other side, specific the opposite aspect of view,on thin guys,they need and body fat.It can't have someone mass body with not body fat.What I want to say ok ,it may need protein etc the muscle but with body fat I think, the muscle , is  more visible.So,conclusion my question is if want to have a visible biceps does body fat help or it does "bad" to gain muscle? I will make an exception to abs.I know to define more the abs low fat needs.What about other muscles?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your muscles will be more defined if you have less body fat covering them up.

Muscles are built by protein and amino acid structures, fat has a role to play in nutrition but it lacks the ability (amino acids) to construct or repair muscle tissues.